# How to keep checkbox array checked after form submission

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have the following codes to show dynamic checkboxes.

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $oaName = $result['oaName'];
    echo '<input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxArray[]" value="'.$oaName.'" style="float:left;"'; ?> <?php if(isset($_POST['checkBoxArray'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> <?php echo '>'; ?>
}
```

I want to retain status of only those checkboxes that I checked as checked after form submission. But with the above codes, all checkboxes are showing checked after form submission. Does anyone know what am i doing wrong here?

**Edit 1**

`checkBoxArray[]` are checkboxes names which are getting from database

Comment: because you are checking `isset` `checkBoxArray`, if it founds `checkBoxArray` then it will check all the checkbox

Comment: Which one should I check for isset then?

Comment: What is in `$_POST['checkBoxArray']`?

Comment: Those are checkboxes names calling from database

Comment: Post name of the checkbox

Comment: Those are not fixed. Those are dynamic names based on what is entered in database. Even the number of checkboxes are not fixed

Comment: You have to check whether that checkbox value is true or false. Just post sample values of `checkBoxArray[]` in question

Comment: `name="checkBoxArray[]"` is an array so it shows all values of checkbox. For example first use `name="checkBoxArray[0]"` and then what you get

Comment: checkBoxArray sample values are some string values (Eg: A, B, C etc). Like I mentioned, the number of checkboxes, values and names are all dynamic. This code is inside a while loop.

Comment: You need to store checkStatus in db so that when you retrieve the data after submitting you can check that status, if `checkStatus == true || checkStatus == yes` then checked else not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few trials, I am able to get it done by the following way. The key here is the use of `in_array`

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $oaName = $result['oaName'];
    echo '<div class = "checkbox-group" required ><input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxArray[]" value="'.$oaName.'" style="float:left;"'; ?> <?php if(in_array($oaName,$_POST['checkBoxArray'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> <?php echo '></div>
}
```

Comment: This will also help: You need to store checkStatus in db so that when you retrieve the data after submitting you can check that status, if checkStatus == true || checkStatus == yes then checked else not

Comment: Thank you @PathikVejani for your time and effort